# How can I access a property (DRIVER/CODRIVER) of an object?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, properties

This is my object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ID] => 1
    [TEAM] => 1
    [TEAM_NAME] => TEAM_NAME
    [FIRST_NAME] => FIRST_NAME
    [LAST_NAME] => LAST_NAME
    [DRIVER/CODRIVER] => Driver
    [CREATED_DATE] => 2014-05-19 03:55:36
    [MODIFIED_DATE] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [STATUS_USER] => Active
)

$obj->ID //getting ID value working
$obj->TEAM_NAME //getting team name working
$obj->DRIVER/CODRIVER // not showing any data not working
```

How to access the property `DRIVER/CODRIVER` of the object?

Comment: `$obj->{'DRIVER/CODRIVER'}`?

Comment: Thanks to all for quick reply.

Comment: @Mahendra you are welcome. I would suggest you to choose one of the answers you find the best for you and accept it so that your question appears as answered in the questions feed. However, taking a look at the times, I think putvande was the first one to give the solution in the comments above, so I will give it's comment +1, too bad his rep. won't increase by that.

Comment: Nice thing that you accepted the answer with the min. rep. @Mahendra. Also your question is a good one, so +1 to you too. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$obj->{"DRIVER/CODRIVER"}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/154736)

Comment: Nice demo! I would suggest stating that the `/` is causing a `division` to happen (so that future readers can understand what causes the problem). If you do that, you'll get my +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$obj->{"DRIVER/CODRIVER"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

`$obj->{'DRIVER/CODRIVER'};`

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WXxoBv)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the *slash*, which implies `division`.

Try

`$obj->{'DRIVER/CODRIVER'}`

This is OK

`$obj->TEAM_NAME`

because it has an *underscore*.

However, if it was `TEAM/NAME`, you should do:

`$obj->{'TEAM/NAME'}`

Comment: That's the actual thing why I accepted that user answer...Thanks for understanding G.Samaras. Actually I thought to accept your answer but unfortunately I have taken that decision any how I'll give you 3 +1 up votes for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$obj->{"DRIVER/CODRIVER"}
```

else it will be consider as a **divison**  `$obj->DRIVER/CODRIVER`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :  1**

```
$arr =  (array) $obj;  // create associative array from object
echo $arr['DRIVER/CODRIVER'];
```

**Solution :  2**

```
echo $obj->{"DRIVER/CODRIVER"};
```